How to use custom user with ASP.NET identity user manager?
I have a custom application user created which I'm using in my identity stores/user managers/etc. but no matter what I do it continues to try to utilize AspNetUsers table rather than the ApplicationUser table generated from the migrations.
Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CoreContext>();

ApplicationUser.cs:
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string>
{
    public int? TestValue { get; set; }
}

In my HomeController:
public HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

Index method:
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var test = _userManager.Users.ToList();
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync('testnew@email.com');   //user exists in SQL table

    return View();
}

I cleared out my AspNetUsers table, but not my ApplicationUser SQL table, and it still tries to pull from AspNetUsers even when I use UserManager<ApplicationUser>.
Any help is appreciated.
I tried overwriting ASP.NET Identity classes with ApplicationUser class. I expect data to pull from appropriate table.

Solution was to call b.Entity<ApplicationUser>.ToTable("ApplicationUser")
Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56132511/24293704
